What does "the first refspec fetched" refer to in the Git documentation?
While reading the git documentation on branch.<name>.merge, I came across the following sentence:

Without this option, git pull defaults to merge the first refspec fetched.

My understanding is that refspecs are not git objects that can be fetched, but are instead specifications of mappings from remote to local ref namespaces.
How can a refspec itself be fetched, and what does "first refspec fetched" mean here?

Seems to me there's only one sensible read, could you give a sample of the sensible reads you can't choose between?

A refspec is a mapping between a remote ref to a local ref, $remote:$local for fetch and $local:$remote for push. Both of the refs refer to the same git object. I think the first refspec fetched means the git object referenced by the refs.

You already understand what refspecs are.  I see no gap that this question addresses.

@jthill My problem is that I have 0 sensible reads currently.
When I read this, I have no idea what the expected behavior is if the option is missing.
If you have one sensible read, could you please share it?

Deleting random lines you don't understand, not a step on any path to clarity I've ever heard of.

@jthill I'm still waiting on your one sensible read so I don't need to delete lines to try to understand things. :)

It's going to take me some time to figure out the confusion of ideas that produced your question, I see you've been using Git for a while and given some good answers so it isn't what it first appeared to be.
